# Do I need to buy an SSL certificate for my new domain?

Tags: django, heroku, https, dns, namecheap

I was hosting my app on Heroku and it said it was "secure" in the domain bar with no problem. I have the following setting on:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

Now I added my own domain and reconfigured my app to point to the domain. Did I lose some sort of SSL by doing this?

Sometimes now I get an error when I try to load the webpage that says:

> ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe.

Heroku provides HTTPS automatically for default `myapp.herokuapp.com` domains, but for custom domains you'll have to do a bit of extra work.

### ACM

The easiest solution is to use [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management), which is powered by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). This can be as easy as running

```
heroku certs:auto:enable
```

However, this feature is only available for paid dynos. It's "free" in the sense that it is included with paid dynos, but if you aren't already on a paid dyno you'll have to upgrade to use it.

### Heroku SSL

If you don't want to use ACM for whatever reason, you can also bring your own certificate with [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl). Configuration is a bit more involved, but you get more control over the certificate vendor and you can use it with free dynos if you wish.